# Adding methods to prototype - once at a time vs. all at once

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is there any difference between

```
function Person() {};

Person.prototype.eat   = function(){};
Person.prototype.speak = function(){};
```

and

```
function Person() {};

Person.prototype = {
    eat:   function(){},
    speak: function(){}
};
```

Notice that the question only apply to a non-inheriting function.

Most examples use the first option, why not just use the second if there is more than one method?

Also, the second option may mislead to think that the existing prototype is being replaces, whereas in the first one it is being added to. In other words, does a javascript function has a public prototype that the second option can override?

Comment: There is a semantic difference; are you asking if there is a practical difference? A performance difference? Are there any edge cases with doing one over the other? "Is there any difference in A vs B" is unclear. One is "A", the other is "B".

Comment: I've edited the question - adding exactly what's confusing. Particularly that it may appear that on the second option you replace the existing prototype; that's what I mean by 'different'.

Comment: The second option *does* actually replace the existing prototype! That's why you can't use that option if you want to inherit from another 'class' such as in `Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);` Trying to use `Employee.prototype = { ... };` after that will remove the inheritance from `Person`.

Comment: Thank you. Considering the second option is used for a 'clean' (non inheriting) function. A function has private prototype (__prototype), but is the public one empty?

Comment: @Izhaki The unmodified prototype of a function does not have any "own" properties, if that's what you're asking: `function C() {} for(var prop in C.prototype) { console.log(prop) }` prints out nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The second replaces the object of type Person inside the prototype with an object of type Object (generic object) - since you are not actually inheriting another object, the difference is minor (if you were inheriting, the second would effectively "negate" the inheritance, as all inherited methods would be gone).

In fact, the only thing that comes to mind is that you will be losing the [.constructor property of the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). In other words, in the first example, `Person.prototype.constructor === Person` will equal true, while in the second it would equal false.